# Проект.exe вызвал срабатывание точки останова

Tags: c++

Задание:
1) Сформировать одномерный массив целых чисел, используя датчик случайных чисел.
2) Распечатать полученный массив.
3) Удалить все элементы равные 0.
4) Добавить после первого четного элемента массива элемент со значением M[I-1]+2.
5) Распечатать полученный массив.

Методические указания:
1) При выполнении работы используются динамические массивы. Определяются сами массивы, затем пользователь вводит реальную длину массива и работает с массивом той длины, которую он сам указал.
2) При уменьшении или увеличении длины массива необходимо создавать новый массив нужной длины, и заполнять его элементами старого массива.

Программа выдаёт правильный ответ, но почему то срабатывает точка останова при очищении памяти массива. Подскажите, пожалуйста, что нужно сделать?

Код Program.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <ctime>
#include "Header.h"


using namespace std;

int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL)); // Используем генератор случайных чисел, взяв в качестве базы текущее время
    cout << "Enter the length of the array: ";
    int t;
    cin >> t;
    int *arr1 = Massiv1(t);

    for (int i = 0; i < t; i++)  // Выводим созданный массив
    {
        cout << arr1[i] << "  ";
    }
    cout << endl;

    int p = Massiv2(arr1, t);
    int *arr2 = Massiv3(arr1, p, t);
    delete[] arr1; // Очищение памяти массива
    int *arr4 = Massiv4(p, arr2);
    bool elfinded = element(p, arr4);

    if (elfinded == true) // Если есть чётный элемент, то увеличиваем память массива на 1
    {
        p++;
    }

    int m = p;
    delete[] arr2; // Очищение памяти массива
    int *arr3 = Massiv5(m, arr4);
    delete[] arr4; // Очищение памяти массива
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) // Выводим полученный массив
    {
        cout << arr3[i] << "  ";
    }
    cout << endl;

    delete[] arr3; // Очищение памяти массива
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Код: Header.h

```
int* Massiv1(int);
int Massiv2(int*, int);
int* Massiv3(int*, int, int);
int* Massiv4(int, int*);
bool element(int, int*);
int* Massiv5(int, int*);
```

Код: AnotherOne.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <conio.h>
#include "Header.h"

using namespace std;

/*Функция для создания массива*/
int* Massiv1(int t)
{
    int *arr1 = new int[t]; // Выделение памяти под массив

    for (int i = 0; i < t; i++) // Создаём массив при помощи генератора случайных чисел
    {
        arr1[i] = rand() % 10;
    }
    return arr1;
}

/*Функция для выявления размера памяти массива*/
int Massiv2(int* arr1, int t)
{
    int n = 0; int k = 0;
    int p = t - n;
    for (int i = 0; i < t; i++) // Цикл для проверка элемента на равность нулю
    {
        if (arr1[i] == 0) // Считаем количество элементов, равные нулю
        {
            n++;
        }
    }
    p = t - n;
    return p;
}


/*Функция для создания массива*/
int* Massiv3(int* arr1, int p, int t)
{
    int* arr2 = new int[p]; // Выделение памяти под массив
    int k = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < t; i++) // Цикл для создания массива
    {
        if (arr1[i] != 0) // Проверка элемента на равность нулю
        {
            arr2[k] = arr1[i];
            k++;
        }
    }
    return arr2;
}

/*Функция для создания массива*/
int* Massiv4(int p, int* arr2)
{
    int* arr4 = new int[p]; // Выделение памяти под массив
    for (int i = 0; i < p; i++) // Цикл для создания массива
    {
        arr4[i] = arr2[i];
    }
    return arr4;
}

/*Функция выясняет, нужно ли добавлять элемент в массив*/
bool element(int p, int* arr4)
{
    bool elfinded = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < p; i++) // Цикл для выяснения, нужно ли добавлять элемент
    {
        if (arr4[i] % 2 == 0 && i != 0) // Если условие удовлетворяет, то булевая переменная принимает значение "истина" 
        {
            elfinded = true;
            i = p;
        }
    }
    return elfinded;

}

/*Функция для создания нового массива*/
int* Massiv5(int m, int* arr4)
{
    int *arr3 = new int[m]; // Выделение памяти под массив
    for (int i = 0; i < m-1; i++) // Цикл для создания массива
    {
        arr3[i] = arr4[i];
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < m - 1; i++) // Цикл для добаваления после первого четного элемента массива элемент со значением arr4[i-1]+2
    {
        if (arr4[i] % 2 == 0 && i != 0) // Поиск элемента
        {
            for (int j = m; j != i; j--) // Цикл для присваивания элементов новому массиву
            {
                arr3[j + 1] = arr4[j];
            }
            arr3[i + 1] = arr4[i - 1] + 2;
            i = m - 1; // Выход из цикла
        }
    }
    return arr3;
}
```

Comment: здесь http://cpp.sh/ норм твой код компилится ))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Смотрим вашу `Massiv5`:

```
int *arr3 = new int[m]; // Выделение памяти под массив
```

А теперь -

```
        for (int j = m; j != i; j--) // Цикл для присваивания элементов новому массиву
        {
            arr3[j + 1] = arr4[j];
```

Ну, и **куда** вы пишете? В какой по счету элемент? И где он находится?...

P.S. Я не искал ошибку в выполнении вашего задания в смысле его смысла :) - это уже самостоятельно...

Comment: Спасибо! Дальше уже сам)

Comment: Даю бесплатный совет :) - в таких случаях натыкивайте в подозрительные места `assert`ы - очень способствует...